# Arduino temperature sensor value is too high

Tags: arduino

When I run this code, I only get a high temperature as shown in the following picture.

How do I connect the pins to work properly?

A0-SIM

A1-RST

Can you explain it this way?

```arduino
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>

Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Adafruit MLX90614 test");  

  mlx.begin();  
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Ambient = "); Serial.print(mlx.readAmbientTempC()); 
  Serial.print("*C\tObject = "); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempC()); Serial.println("*C");
  Serial.print("Ambient = "); Serial.print(mlx.readAmbientTempF()); 
  Serial.print("*F\tObject = "); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempF()); Serial.println("*F");

  Serial.println();
  delay(500);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the sensor you are using? (name, code etc.)

Comment: The sensor I'm using is GY-MCU90614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sensor is using Serial communication interface, while Adafruit library is using I2C interface. So you can't use that library.

You need to connect Tx to Pin 10 on Arduino Uno, and Rx to Pin 11, and run the sketch shows [here](https://github.com/Play-Zone/MCU90615).

Answer (score 1):

The Adafruit library is for a bare sensor or sensor module with an I2C connection, but the module you have uses a serial connection.

If you want to use the Adafruit library as-is, you need to get a module or sensor that can connect over I2C (one that has pins marked SCL/SDA).

If you want to use the module you have, you need to find an Arduino library that supports it (I don't know of one), or do some programming yourself.